# Ninject generic bindings

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I am building an application using Ninject and ASP.NET MVC 3.
Is it possible with Ninject to supply a generic binding within a module like this:

```
 Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(SomeConcreteRepository<>));
```

**EDIT:** 
And then for a specific type , create a class that inherits from SomeConcreteRepository:

```
Bind(typeof(IRepository<Person>)).To(typeof(PersonConcreteRepository));
```

This throws an exception that multiple bindings are available. However, is there another approach to this? Are there other DI frameworks for .NET which support this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a nasty fix but for the scenario at hand it works:

```
public class MyKernel: StandardKernel
  {
    public MyKernel(params INinjectModule[] modules) : base(modules) { }

    public MyKernel(INinjectSettings settings, params INinjectModule[] modules) : base(settings, modules) { }

    public override IEnumerable<IBinding> GetBindings(Type service)
    {
      var bindings = base.GetBindings(service);


      if (bindings.Count() > 1)
      {
        bindings = bindings.Where(c => !c.Service.IsGenericTypeDefinition);
      }

      return bindings;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I used this same approach, though I refined the if statement to verify that there is one non-generic service binding first

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the second line. Simply register the open generic types:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(SomeConcreteRepository<>));
```

and later fetch a specific repository like this:

```
var repo = kernel.Get<IRepository<Person>>();
```

or you can also [use a provider](http://groups.google.com/group/ninject/browse_thread/thread/b2df51230bed8195).

Comment: @sTodorov, did you see the provider link I posted in my answer?

Comment: Yes I did thank you. I am currently looking into extending the providers, or creating a customized Kernel and overriding a few methods. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: thanks for your help. Fixed it in a different way. See Answer above

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ExtendedNinjectKernal : StandardKernel
{
    public ExtendedNinjectKernal(params INinjectModule[] modules) : base(modules) { }

    public ExtendedNinjectKernal(INinjectSettings settings, params INinjectModule[] modules) : base(settings, modules) { }

    public override IEnumerable<IBinding> GetBindings(Type service)
    {
        var bindings = base.GetBindings(service);

        //If there are multiple bindings, select the one where the service does not have generic parameters
        if (bindings.Count() > 1 && bindings.Any(a => !a.Service.IsGenericTypeDefinition))
            bindings = bindings.Where(c => !c.Service.IsGenericTypeDefinition);

        return bindings;
    }
}
```